# Getting libboost-all-dev for ARM machine Linux--UHD Ubuntu 12.04 ZyBo ARMv7 32bit

Tags: 12.04, embedded-system, arm

## Basic info:

I need to install UHD on my ZyBo board (by Digilent and Xilinx), but cannot. I have Xillinux Ubuntu 12.04 installed on it. It has an ARMv7 architecture of 32bits.(Go to bottom for question).
The UHD software can be installed by following the instructions here:

**Installation option 1:**

http://code.ettus.com/redmine/ettus/projects/uhd/wiki/UHD_Linux

**An alternative installation process is:**

Install Git and download source code:

```
    sudo apt-get install git
    git clone git://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd.git
```

Install all needed dependencies (see build guide):

```
    sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev python-cheetah doxygen python-docutils
```

Build-essential is a well packaged C++ library which is another needed

```
    sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Install and run cmake:

```
    sudo apt-get install cmake
```

Next, to run the cmake program:

```
    cd uhd/host
    mkdir build
    cd build
    cmake ../
```

Ensure that all tests that are related to the main, necessary dependencies are successful.

Install and setup library path:

```
    make
    make test
    sudo make install
    cd uhd/host/build/lib
    cp libuhd.so /etc/ld.so.conf.d
    sudo ldconfig
    sudo reboot
```

(I have also tried other website instructions and work-arounds).

## PROBLEM / QUESTION:

However, the issue is that this software was made for i386 and amd64 machines. The ZyBo has an ARMv7 architecture. I used one installation guide which required the dependency of package: libboost-all-dev which is not available for my architecture. Therefore I was only to install half the requirements for UHD.
Does anyone know how to build the installation so that it can run on ARMv7 architecture or how to download the package libboost-all-dev onto an ARMv7 processor?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UHD works for ARM machines. However you have to change the settings on Update Manager in Linux to search for updates from (universe) which has the libboost-all-dev library